# How do I validate a JSON body using go's validator to make sure only the specified fields are sent with the JSON body?

Tags: go, validation

I have the following struct.

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code     uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;" json:"code"`
    Name     string    `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Quantity int       `json:"qty" validate:"required,min=0"`
}
```

I want to ensure that when parsing the JSON body, I only receive both `name` and `quantity`. If the body has any other fields, e.g. `code` or any other irrelevant fields, I want the validator to invalidate the JSON given. How can I achieve this with this package: `"github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"`?

Comment: Before running validation you can use [DisallowUnknownFields](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.19.5#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields) when decoding the json into the struct. Note however that, given that the Product has a `json:"code"` field, the `code` field in the incoming request's body would not throw an error. You can declare a new struct if you like, or change `json:"code"` to `json:"-"` (though then it will be dropped from output if you use `Product` for marshaling).

Comment: @mkopriva Nice! Thanks for the info about marshaling, I guess I'd have to create two separate structs then.

Comment: I can only give you advice not to use one model at all levels of the application. Divide models into transport and internal ones, and make adapters between them. This will save you from many problems, including those in which you break the backward compatibility of the services API.