# Forbid extra keys in request body of gin golang

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin, grpc-go

I want to do a validation for sending the extra keys in the JSON body.

My Model

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `json:"username" validate:"required" gorm:"unique"`
    Email    string `json:"email" validate:"required,email" gorm:"unique"`
    Password string `json:"password" validate:"required" `

}
```

Now if someone sends an `id:111` in the request body then it gets save into db. I want to stop that only.

Validator that I'm using is "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10" but it's not working

```
validate := validator.New()
err := validate.Struct(user)
```

Comment: Does gorm.Model contain an id field?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75311096/how-do-i-validate-a-json-body-using-gos-validator-to-make-sure-only-the-specifi?noredirect=1#comment132893088_75311096

Comment: @J.Titus No. But still, it accepts it as database table have it.

Answer (score 0):

The go-playground/validator package you're using won't validate unknown fields in the JSON body by default. To validate only the fields in the struct, you can use the **omitempty** tag:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `json:"username" validate:"required" gorm:"unique"`
    Email    string `json:"email" validate:"required,email" gorm:"unique"`
    Password string `json:"password" validate:"required" `
    ID       int    `json:"id,omitempty" validate:"-"`
}
```

The **omitempty** tag means that the ID field won't be marshaled into JSON if its value is zero-value (0 for int). The validate:"-" tag means that the field won't be validated.